# how to point towards a method given variable python

Tags: python, methods

```
possibleRequests = ['test', 'test1']

def inboxReader():
        global inbox
        tempInbox = []
        tempInbox = inbox.inboxMessage #inboxMesage remains filled?
        print(inbox.inboxMessage, 'inboxReader')
        i = 0
        while (i < len(tempInbox)):
            if (tempInbox[i] in possibleRequests):
                print('THIS IS WORKING')
            #print(i)
            i+=1
```

I want to be able to have possible requests point towards a method to run rather than have a long list of if statments. What am I able to do in order to have a variable point towards and run a method.

Cheers,

Marc

Comment: I would like more info, what is inbox.inboxMessage? a list? where do you want to "have possible requests point towards a method to run rather than have a long list of if statments"?

Comment: You can store functions (and methods) in variables (e.g. `f = inboxReader; f()`)..

Comment: inbox is a class that I call its an array.

how would I go about doing what thebjorn said? it seams to be the thing i'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create a dictionary of functions then refer to it with tempInbox[i]. Example code below:

```
def func_a(x):
    return x

def func_b(x):
    return x*10

tempInbox = (2,3)

fn_dict = {"a":func_a,"b":func_b}
print fn_dict["a"](tempInbox[0]) # returns 2
print fn_dict["b"](tempInbox[1]) # returns 30
```

Comment: awesome this is exactly what I need